# Mapstruct one mapper method for multiple sources

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have multiple sources, which are used conditionaly, for ex:

```
@Mapper(uses = CustomMapper.class)
public interface CarFilterMapper {
 default CarFilterDTO toCarFilterDTO(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (obj instanceof com.model.cars.v1.car) {
            com.model.cars.v1.CAR targetCar = (com.model.cars.v1.CAR) car;
            return toCarFilterDTO(targetCar);
        } else if (obj instanceof com.model.cars.v2.CAR) {
            com.model.cars.v2.CAR targetCar = (com.model.cars.v2.CAR) car;
            return toCarFilterDTO(targetCar);

            }
            
    @CarMapping
    CarFilterDTO toCarFilterDTO(com.model.cars.v1.CAR.SAL obj);
    
    @CarMapping
    CarFilterDTO toCarFilterDTO(com.model.cars.v2.CAR.SAL obj);
```

Also I have CarMapping:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Mapping(target = "number", source = "SAL.INF.HDR.NUM")
@Mapping(target = "tracking", source = "SAL.INF.HDR.TRCNUM")
@Mapping(target = "hbl", source = ".", qualifiedByName = "toHbl")
public @interface CarMapping {
}
```

My problem is I need to write multiple toHbl methods for all CAR versions(there are 5 versions). I want to avoit that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an in-built solution exactly for this problem, however, as far as I see, this should be solved by composable mappers and I assume they should work in layers. However, the mappings should be still implemented manually for each source.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Mapping(target = "number", source = "SAL.INF.HDR.NUM")
@Mapping(target = "tracking", source = "SAL.INF.HDR.TRCNUM")
public @interface CarMapping {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
    @Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
    @CarMapping
    @Mapping(target = "hbl", source = ".", qualifiedByName = "toHbl1")
    @interface CarMapperToHbl1 {}

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
    @Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
    @CarMapping
    @Mapping(target = "hbl", source = ".", qualifiedByName = "toHbl2")
    @interface CarMapperToHbl2 {}

    // ... others
}
```

The application of this method would be the following:

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

   @CarMapping.CarMapperToHbl1
   CarDto entityToDto(CarEntity entity)

   // ... others
}
```